# How to create a result set with the max value of each TILE and the number of itens in that TILE

Tags: sql, mariadb, postgresql-9.6

If I have a table like this

```
id product_name  price

1   product_1     5    
2   product_2     10 
3   product_3     100
4   product_4     200   
5   product_5     9000
```

If I execute a query like this:

```
 select  price,  ntile(3) over(order by price) as rank from products order by price.
```

It will produce a result roughly like this:

```
   id  product_name   price       rank

    1   product_1     5             1
    2   product_2     10            1
    3   product_3     100           2
    4   product_4     200           2
    5   product_5     9000          3
```

But I would like to expand this a little more and get the max value of each tile and the number of itens on that tile.

```
   price    items
    10       2
    200      2
    9000     1  // I think I won't use the last tile max value, but it's here anyway.
```

I don't have the knoleged to get the result that I want so I little help is welcome.

Comment: Which one is it? MariaDB or PostgreSQL?

Comment: either one will do, I am using an online tool  to run the query.

Answer (score 1):

How about just using aggregation?

```
select max(price), count(*)
from (select price,  ntile(3) over (order by price) as rank
      from products
     ) p
group by rank
order by price
```

Just a caution:  `ntile()` creates equal-sized bins, so the boundary values may be split across multiple bins.